# Linksys LGS310MPC CLI terminal length

Tags: switch

I've ssh'd into the Linksys cli with powershell, and when I do a "show current running-config" the config is so long that it feels like I'm holding down enter for an eternity. Powershell's output history is much longer than putty I've noticed so I'm hoping someone knows the linksys command to set "terminal length 0" like you would for a CISCO. (terminal length 0 did not work by the way) None of the commands in the help menu seemed to indicate there was a command for setting the terminal length so if you just can't, let me know. Otherwise, if there is another way to export the config file to the device I'm sessioned in with that would work just as well and be just as great.

Answer (score 1):

Late to the party, but 69 views over 10 months, at least a few people are interested.

Switch Model Name:  LGS352C
Firmware Version:  1.01.01.02

Commands:

```
config terminal;
set cli pagination off
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).